# How to identify if a given file is batch file by reading its content and not by extension?

Tags: batch-file

For executables like EXE, MSI and MSP I am able to detect file type by reading its few bytes. But I am not able to detect BATCH file by reading its content. User can change the BATCH file extension so I don't want to rely on extension to detect a BATCH file. Is there a way to detect BATCH file by reading its content programmatically?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No there isn't, it is a plain text file format, so there is not way of determining it, without some complex algorithm which can determine every possible valid command which can be run/executed by the batch file interpreter, _(and even then, I've seen some on here which cannot be)_. Apart from that, your question is off topic for this site, which assist you with an issue with your provided code. This site does not answer research questions for you.

Comment: If you change the file extension to something other than `bat` or `cmd`, it ceases to become a batch script, since Windows refuses to run it. The `file` command that's built into WSL will recognize it as a batch file if it starts with `@echo off`, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

(**Note**:As Compo said that there isn't a clear way of doing this without a sophisticated algorithm and also this question would have been much better at superuser or another platform(and some of you might not like this but future viewer's can get some help from it and it's ok with a downvote --the message will be deleted by me in a while).

Here there is a batch file that might help you with your program(not exactly your answer).

```
@echo off
rem probably the batch file isn't well written.you can add commands for better detection
rem and also might have great limitations 
rem improvements are welcomed
set file=%1
findstr /C:"@echo off" /C:"set" /C:"set /p" /C:"pause" /C:"echo" /C:"pause >nul" /C:"cd" /C:"call" /C:"goto" /C:"if" /C:"type" /C:"rem" /C:"copy" /C:"move" /C:"cls" /C:"wmic" %file% >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Appears to be a batch file
) else (
echo Doesn't appear to be a batch file
)
```

Comment: Very few of my actual batch scripts ever begin with, or contain `@echo off`, and you should be aware that I can use the command `echo`, and many of the other strings you've used, in other plain text files too, even powershell and bash scripts. In short it cannot be done. For instance, I could run a command line utility or other executable from a powershell script, and the same command can be equally used in a batch file. Also, please do not use broken labels in your batch files, `::`, if you want to add commentary, use the `Rem` command. There are other things which require improvement too.

Comment: @Compo Exactly! this batch-file will only identify basic scripts.and as said has ```great limitations``` it's just a little wind to help pass the ocean.

Comment: Why post it then, it absolutely does not determine whether the file is a batch script. What happens if it is just a plain text document whereby a user has made some notes about useful commands, or simply pasted commands for future use, but not given the file a bat or cmd extension, in order to ensure that it isn't mistaken as a usable script and executed. At the outset, the first thing I'd assume your script must do is look at the extensions, if it is not `.bat` or `.cmd`, then it obviously cannot be ran as one and therefore wouldn't technically need to be parsed for its string content!

Comment: The OP specifically stated, that they do not wish to rely on the extension, but they did not state, that it could not form part of the identification process. Also, as I've mentioned on this site before, please do not assume that I'm a Mr, or wish to be identified as such. I therefore ask that you immediately remove that term from your answer, we do not live in a world where people must identify as a particular gender.

Comment: so each text file that talks about ident*if*ying or re*set*ting a counter is a batch file? Also most of those words are quite common in many programming languages, and even in "normal English" texts